# How to update a string by inserting characters in between

Tags: sql, ms-access, jet-sql

In MS-Access, I have a text field labeled idStr and currently, the data shows like this "000000000". I would like to transform the string by writing an update query and making it like this: "000-00-0000". In other words, I'd like to insert - (hyphen) after the third character and after the fifth character.

The only solution I've seen is to write a select query using left and right but I'm actually attempting to update the string and make it permanent

Comment: Take that SELECT and rewrite as an UPDATE query. The function you wrote with `LEFT()` `RIGHT()` and `MID()` will be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the string, you can put the logic in a `update` statement:

```
update t
    set idstr = left(idstr, 3) & "-" & mid(idstr, 4, 2) & "-" & right(idstr, 4);
```

Comment: I was unaware of the mid function. Thanks!